# Making a simple distance converter from stratch

Tags: javascript, firefox, notepad++

Ok I'm trying to convert miles to kilometers and it has to go both ways in javascript.
I have very little lines that I started and I'm stumped at this point, I don't know how to continue. This is what pathetic code I have now.

```
Var = x;
x = prompt("Enter Miles to be converted into kilometeres");
x = parseInt(x);
```

If anything try to sprout ideas in my head on what to do. I would like to help myself but I'm asking for ideas at this point. If it goes past Wednesday I might ask for full blown help.

Comment: `var km = miles * 1.6;`

Comment: Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LwDKf/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){ // listening to click event
  var target = event.target.id; //Checking id of clicked button
  var convertValue = 0; // Initializing 0 value
  if(target == "demMiles" || target == "demKm"){  // If button is clicked
      var distance = prompt("Please enter distance"); //Will open prompt window
    if(distance != null){  // If prompt window is not empty
      if(target =="demMiles"){   // Checking for mile to km conversion
        convertValue = distance *1.6;
      }
      else if(target =="demKm"){  // checking for km to mile conversion
          convertValue = distance /1.6;
      }
     document.getElementById("dist").innerHTML =   
       "Converted distance is " +convertValue;   // Displaying the value
    }

  }
  })
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/os30ptzu/1/)

Comment: Ok so I have to remove the comments and add in more stuff?